# Mongodb Authentication failed on database

Tags: php, mongodb

While I'm trying to connect to Mongodb I'm receiving 
*"Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on database 'wai' with username 'wai_web': auth fails in /var/www/dev/web/functions.php:12'"*
although the login and password are correct.

functions.php:

```
<?php
function get_db()
{
    $mongo = new MongoClient(
       "mongodb://localhost:27017/",
        [
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'user',
            'db' => 'wai',
        ]);
    $db = $mongo->wai;

    return $db;
}
```

I use 'functions.php' in others files by:

```
require_once 'functions.php';
$db = get_db();
```

Comment: anyone? I'd be grateful for help

Comment: which mongodb version you are using, it seems they have changed authentication mechanism to SCRAM-SHA-1, so you must have the driver in sync with the db version. I had to upgrade my spring-data jar since I was getting same error.